# Start multiple neo4j servers from Neo4j Desktop

Tags: neo4j, multiple-databases, neo4j-desktop

I recently downloaded and successfully used "neo4j desktop" (v 1.0.10), which allows you to create and manage different projects and databases.

I need to spawn two databases instances at the same time. I changed the ports for them both from the confs and I can start them successfully on such ports but not together.

When I press the start button on one server the other one automatically stops.

Is it possible to use such feature on neo4j desktop or should I just use the normal neo4j server installation?

Comment: I faced the similar issue and I concluded we can not do this with Neo4J desktop application.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can not run multiple projects together from Neo4J desktop application. 
You need to use the `neo4j server` for this purpose.
What I did is :

1. Download Neo4J server(Community Release) from [here](https://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/#releases)
2. Unzip the tar
3. Copy unzipped directory to two different locations.
4. Updated following configurations in conf/neo4j.conf file for both directories (with different values obviously !) :

   ```
    dbms.active_database=<name-of-db-dir>
    dbms.directories.data=<path-to-dir>
    # Bolt connector
    dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
    #dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
    dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=localhost:XXXX

    # HTTP Connector. There must be exactly one HTTP connector.
    dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
    dbms.connector.http.listen_address=localhost:XXXX

    # HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
    dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
    dbms.connector.https.listen_address=localhost:XXXX
   ```
5. start `Neo4J server` from respective directories using command : `./bin/neo4j start`.
6. It will start Neo4j server at specified ports on localhost !